# Ionic array filter does not filter

Tags: javascript, arrays, ionic-framework

I have a list of items in an array.  Each element in the array contains the following:

```
id
date
status
name
description
```

I am trying to create a second array which will contain all the elements from the first array where the status = 'pending'.

I am executing the following code in my home.ts file:

```ts
showPending(){
    this.pendingItems = this.items;
    this.pendingItems.filter((item) => {return item.status === 'pending'});
    this.navCtrl.push(ShowPendingPage, {
    pendingItems: this.pendingItems      
    });
  }
```

When I run my application, I add 3 elements into the items array.  2 elements have a status of pending and 1 has a status of complete.  When I execute the above code, the ShowPendingPage gets pushed.  I execute this code in the ShowPendingPage.ts file:

```
this.passedArray = this.navParams.get('pendingItems')
```

and I execute the following in my ShowPendingPage.html:

```
  <ion-content>
  <ion-list>
      <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let item of passedArray">
        <ion-item [ngClass]="item.status">
            {{item.name}} - Added {{item.date}}
        </ion-item>  
        <ion-item-options side="right">
          <button ion-button color="light" (click)="viewItem(item)">View</button>
        </ion-item-options>
      </ion-item-sliding>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
```

The resulting array contains all 3 elements of the original array.  It should only contain 2 elements, the two where I set the status to pending.

Anybody with better eyes than me that can see what I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) creates a new array with the filtered elements and is not *in place*.

> The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

Also

> filter() does not mutate the array on which it is called.

You just have to set it to your variable.

```
this.pendingItems = this.pendingItems.filter((item) => {return item.status === 'pending'});
```